# Using JNI with External Libraries

Tags: java-native-interface, itk

I know the basics (very, very basic) of JNI, as in I can embed a super simple C++ program in Java. But for a project I'm working on (the reason I'm trying to learn JNI) the C++ code uses an external library- ITK for medical segmentation and registration. In making the .dll package that will be accessed by Java, how can I include the ITK code that the C++ uses so the larger Java program will run properly?

Comment: The process stays the same regardless of what your library does and what other libraries it uses: you need to provide a set of functions that are visible from the Java side (`Java_your_package_AndClass_Foo...`), and those functions can then call other functions internally and do whatever it is they need to do.